# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method initializeInstanceForTests() MockWebServer on androidTest

Tags: android, mockwebserver

I can't initialize MockWebServer on androidTest folder. I've already added this line on my gradle
    `androidTestCompile('com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.6.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okio', module: 'okio'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }`.

I tried to follow the implementation from https://github.com/riggaroo/android-retrofit-test-examples. I've cloned the project, change the version of MockWebServer used by this example to the latest one and it still works fine but the implementation from my project still gives me same error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method initializeInstanceForTests()V in class Ld/a/a; or its super classes (declaration of 'd.a.a' appears in /data/app/com.agri.fma-2/base.apk)
at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.<clinit>(MockWebServer.java:101)
at com.agri.fma.activity.TestInputTenantActivity.setUp(TestInputTenantActivity.java:68)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1886)
```

Below, TestInputTenantActivity code

```
public class TestInputTenantActivity {
    @Rule public IntentsTestRule<InputTenantActivity> activityTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(InputTenantActivity.class, false, false);

    @Inject InputTenantView view;

    @Mock
    SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;
    private TestMainApplication app;
    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        app = (TestMainApplication) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                .getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();

        DaggerTestInputTenantComponent.builder().testAppComponent(app.getAppComponent())
                .testInputTenantModule(new TestInputTenantModule())
                .build().inject(this);

        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyTenant(){
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        onView(withId(R.id.tenant)).perform(typeText(""));
        onView(withId(R.id.action_next)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.tenant)).check(matches(hasErrorText(app.getString(R.string.empty_tenant))));
        intended((hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), LoginActivity.class))), times(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTenantWithWhiteSpace(){
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                Locale.US,
                app.getString(R.string.invalid_string_error),
                "Tenant name");
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        onView(withId(R.id.tenant)).perform(typeText(TENANT_WITH_WHITESPACE));
        onView(withId(R.id.action_next)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.tenant)).check(matches(hasErrorText(errorMessage)));
        intended((hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), LoginActivity.class))), times(0));
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidTenant(){
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(new Intent());
        onView(withId(R.id.tenant)).perform(typeText(VALID_TENANT));
        onView(withId(R.id.action_next)).perform(click());
        intended(hasComponent(new ComponentName(getTargetContext(), LoginActivity.class)));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code of `TestInputTenantActivity`

Comment: found the problem. it's because I used proguard on debug